# Apache SSL working with IP but not FQDN

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl

All was well in my little network until I switch internet providers and had to change my IP address on my internal network from 172.16.0.x to 192.168.1.x, they have funky hardware and this is in my house.

So, I have Apache 2.2 running on a machine, when I access it via IP address, the SSL pages come up just fine and load.  When I try to FQDN on the server, it works fine, when I try it on any other machine, they all see the unsigned cert and warn me, then they give me a "connection was reset"

The only Listen statements I have look like this:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

And then this is a trimmed down version of the virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    ServerName www.domain.local:443
    DocumentRoot "k:/apache/htdocs-ssl"

    <Directory k:/apache/htdocs-ssl>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The results from httpd -S:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          secure.domain.com (H:/Apache2.2/conf/sslsettings.conf:11)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server server1.domain.com (H:/Apache2.2/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:22)
         port 80 namevhost server1.domain.com (H:Apache2.2/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:22)
         port 80 namevhost devinst.domain.com (H:Apache2.2/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf:53)
```

Any suggestions on what I might be missing?

Comment: When you created CSR for your self signed certificate did your common name was IP address or FQDN?

Comment: Are the SSL directives in that virtual host?  Can you provide the output from `apachectl -S`?

Comment: did you update your dns to point to this new 192.168. address?  I assume you restarted apache after these changes?  what's in your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: when I used openssl to look at the cert, there is no IP address anywhere in the cert.  I don't have a machine name, the O and OU are both the domain name. (I am using openssl x509 -text -in server.crt to get the info, is there another option?)

Comment: I am adding the results to 'httpd -S' to the main message